# Cascading Isolated Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, isolation, series

I want to implement a few chips for battery management and due to the ADCs of each cell working at bigger voltages each, and each chip (I have to cascade three ICs LTC6803-4) with a maximum voltage lower than the battery maximum, I have thought if this implementation would work:
[image]
I have seen something similar in the application example of the datasheet of the IC:
[image]

Comment: What is your question?  The big takeaway is that you need isolated power supplies and isolated digital interfaces for each stage since each successive stage will be referenced to the first cell in its string.

Comment: Use opto logic tranceivers

Comment: @vir the question is if I can connect the V+ 1 to the V- 2 as it will cause that the IC2 is working in top of IC1(speaking in voltage), so I can measure the 2nd pack of 12 cells, because before the isolation, all the power supply is connected at the same GND

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 ok but at which point?

Comment: All comm ports that need it due to shift in PS- voltage yet common logic ground need a digital isolator.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yes, I would isolate both power supply, and SPI communication, grounding each chip with its own transceiver, but would that schematic work?

Answer (score 1):

> Would that schematic work?

This is basically extrapolating LTC’s 2 stage to 3 , so on the surface , there’s no reason it shouldn’t.

But you have a challenge from me.

1. Define all the qualitative performance reasons to realize this schematic with improvement options.
2. Define all the quantitative of your charger system specs that matter with this BMS and tolerances with fault detection and correction mitigation functions needed that need attention.
3. One of the challenges with cascade BMS is that all batteries must be well matched for capacity and ESR in order the the residual error to be dissipated in heat by the Zener internal diodes.
4. Also consider including individual thermal sensing, which is critical when 1. occurs unexpectedly and the cells are not thermally coupled.
   -This is best done with diode Or’ing than thermistors.

- considering the wide tolerances on e-caps & bulk supercaps, LI Ion batteries are no different.
- worse yet, because the weakest cell has the fastest dV/dt they will become the 1st to become under or over charged.
- when undercharged the ESR rises rapidly below 10% SOC resulting in more heat loss with shared current during operation but excess current shunting during CC charging if 1 cell reaches 100% SOC at 4.2V per cell while the string has not reached CV mode.
- since CV mode uses declining currents, the %C deviation determines how long BMS must shunt up,to the power Max. being charged to the other cells.

  - this may require you to have more than 1 CC mode so the equalization charge layer can catchup in each cell. I.e. CC to 3.8V x36 cells then Monitor IC temp and reduce CC as required by IC temp. or battery temp to 4.2V x36 then go to into CV mode for a time limited final charge. Or consider 4.1Vx36 or longer life.

Disclaimer: I have not used this excellent solution but has great potential for HV packs.(pun intended)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response!
I am going to implement a passive balancer with a low pass filter in between every Cn/Sn port, not just the resistor shown, so all the batteries will be matched externally to the LTC, and so the heat will be disipated by the external diodes(I attach you the reference design that I am basing my sch: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/eval-board-schematic/DC1835A-1-SCH.PDF)

Comment: I need to manage a 30s4p battery, so my intention is to implement 4 exactly boards, capable of 36 cell monitoring each, so I have option to scale to a bigger battery in the future.I want to build the battery with LiPo cells with a nominal value of 3.7(4.2V peak), so when the max voltage is achieved, the BMS will cut the energy going into the battery, and when the voltage is under lets say 3.4V it will cut the energy going out of the battery.
It will also measure temps at different points of the battery to have the heat problem covered too at charging/discharging stages

Comment: Ok but if CC is 5Ah x 4.2V =21W worst case if >10% mismatched after aging, since they all share the same current and you regulated CC on the string until CV on the entire string

Comment: They are 10Ah(with a discharge intensity of 200 A (20 C) Normal, 300 A (30 C) Peak and
charge intensity of 20 A (2 C)), so 42W, if I match all the CV by passive balancing, then all of them will feed the same current, don't they? 
So as much as I balance the voltages between every pair of cells, and have a protection system by under/over voltage, some fuses and current sensors, ans temp sensors at different points, it should be covered, right?

Comment: Nope.  All batteries are like supercaps except >10kF and ESR <50mOhm when new so tolerances depend on batch, age use.  The smallest C charges the fastest dV/dt=Ic/C except for I*ESR drop induces a step I*ESR then the dual layer effect means there are actually 2 or more ESR * C= T time constants, so read my advice carefully

Comment: Ok, so I have to implement like a "charging protocol" as you refer on your last point of decrementing the CC going into the battery keeping in mind the temperatures.

And another thing, this would have the problem of the smallest cell charged/discharged faster?, or how I could charge the cells independently?

Comment: I suggest shortinng the battery to ground to reduce impedance

Comment: @BeatriceUK that requires 200A *4.2V = >800W  to be dumped in battery and balancer dummy load short with 5 MOhm switch

Comment: No Victor BMS extends battery life by preventing voltage runaway but at the cost of excess shared current * delta V  . Only the weakest or smallest C charges the fastest dV/dt=I/C inversely related to C

Comment: Also since weakest battery also raisesESR so it is also the hottest I^2*ESR.. Especially under discharge below 10%SoC

Comment: You can get a rough estimate my binning all your cells for same 100%Voc within 5 mV bins after resting time several hrs or less but measuring Wh or Ah and ESR is how a I expect a CODEX battery tester shud work.

Comment: Good thank you so much for the replys, I will start working,a dn in a few days I will update my advances
Regards!

Comment: Waiting to read your design specs...good luck